# InAppBrowser in Cordova 2.7.0

Tags: crash, cordova, inappbrowser

Is there a solution with the problem when at the time to close inAppBrowser before load the page make crash ios app?

Cordova Version 2.7.0

The inAppBrowser causes ios apps to crash (close without warning) if the "Done" button is clicked within a second or two of opening (of course not every time - but 3 out of 4 tries usually - on both iphone and ipad).

We have tried wrapping all relevant javascript in try/catch blocks and they are not fired. We have also tried registering an event listener on the inAppBrowser error event (also not fired).

It is looking like a PhoneGapBuild issue causing an ios crash.

All and any help / feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just reported the same issue to Cordova at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4995 and suggested possible solution in it. It is the solution we used for our Cordova 2.8.15 iOS application.

You can see more detail at the link above, but in summary, the crash happens because self.inAppBrowserViewController under webViewDidFinishLoad in CDVInAppBrowser.m is nil if webViewDidFinishLoad is called little too late due to rapid closing of browser, which calls browserExit that nils out self.inAppBrowserViewController beforehand. We fixed the issue by nil-checking self.inAppBrowserViewController within webViewDidFinishLoad and using this custom patched CDVInAppBrowser.m

Comment: The problem is officially fixed for CB-4995 in Cordova, and it can be viewed at [https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git;a=commit;h=aa81c326](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git;a=commit;h=aa81c326).

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution described at http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/inappbrowser_causes_ios_apps_to_crash_on_close-15h8ot which worked for me.

It involves adding an event listener to the "exit" event and calling the close() method when this event is fired.

I don't know why this works, but it did for me.

```
var inAppBrowser = window.open("http://google.com","_blank");
inAppBrowser.addEventListener("exit", function(event) {
    inAppBrowser.close();
});
```